# create-react-app SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

I can`t start my server for debug. I get a error.
I start my project in docker

```
nodejs_1  | file:///opt/project/src/index.js:27
nodejs_1  |   <Provider store={store}>
nodejs_1  |   ^
nodejs_1  | 
nodejs_1  | SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'
nodejs_1  |     at Loader.moduleStrategy (internal/modules/esm/translators.js:117:18)
nodejs_1  |     at async link (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:42:21)
azbyka_nodejs_1 exited with code 1
```

my index.js

```
import 'react-app-polyfill/ie11';
import 'react-app-polyfill/stable';
import 'react-perfect-scrollbar/dist/css/styles.css';
import 'react-draft-wysiwyg/dist/react-draft-wysiwyg.css';
import 'react-quill/dist/quill.snow.css';
import 'nprogress/nprogress.css';
import 'src/assets/css/prism.css';
import 'src/mixins/chartjs';
import 'src/mixins/prismjs';
//import 'src/mock';
import { enableES5 } from 'immer';
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import * as serviceWorker from 'src/serviceWorker';
import { SettingsProvider } from 'src/context/SettingsContext';
import { configureStore } from 'src/store';
import { restoreSettings } from 'src/utils/settings';
import App from 'src/App';
require('dotenv').config();
enableES5();

const store = configureStore();
const settings = restoreSettings();

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <SettingsProvider settings={settings}>
      <App />
    </SettingsProvider>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);

serviceWorker.unregister();
```

my .babelrc

```
{
  "presets": [
    "babel-preset-react-app"
  ]
}
```

i`ve changed presets to "presets": ["react", "es2015", "stage-0"]. it hasn`t helped

Can you help me?

Comment: Try deleting .babelrc?

Comment: @Sun it did not help

Comment: i\`ve installed npm install babel-preset-react-app --save-dev and i\`ve changed .babelrc to {  "presets": ["react-app"]} but it has not helped